# Changing colors shown in legend superheat R heat map

Tags: r, legend, heatmap

I have a heat map that has lots of very low values and a few very high ones. The colors we've used seem fine to show these, but the legend is hard to see/read because you can't see the colors at the low end of the range.

Example that is similar is here.  Is there a way to show the legend (below the graph here) as a log scale or something, so that you can see the various purples and blues and the corresponding numbers in the legend rather than those colors all being squished at the left side of the legend scale?

```
library(superheat)
superheat(mtcars)
```

[image]
I tried using legend breaks line, but all that does is shift the numbers on the legend

```
superheat(mtcars),
legend.breaks = c(min(mtcars), 0, max(200)))
```

Comment: looking at the superheat vignette, it looks like you can define your own colour scale using `heat.pal` and `heat.pal.values` to set the breakpoints.

Comment: is `superheat(mtcars, scale = TRUE)` solve your problem?

Comment: doesn't really work - the scale = TRUE and the heat.pal.values both adjusts the scaling inside the heat map, and normalizes the data.  I want the data colors to stay the same but just tweak the scale bar (almost like putting the scalebar on a log scale just to help)